# Understanding awk commands; split, rec and ORS

Tags: awk

I have a piece of code, I am trying to break down and decipher. I need someone that can walk me through what is happening in each step:

```
FNR==NR {
  if (split($1,a, "_") ==3)
  f1[$1]
next
}
NF{
if (split($1, a, "_") ==3 && $1 in f1)
  p=1
  rec=(!rec)?$0:rec ORS $0
next
}
p{
  print rec ORS
  p=0; rec=""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NR` is the total number of records processed (inclusive of the one being processed currently); `FNR` is the number of records processed *in the current file*.  This will only happen for the first file.

```
FNR==NR {
  if (split($1,a, "_") ==3)
  f1[$1]
next
}
```

Similarly, `NF` is the number of fields in the current record.  If it is a blank line, this will be zero, which is "falsy" (as opposed to "truthy"), and so this block will only execute for non-blank lines.  Make a note of the code in this block where the value of `p` is set; that will be important later.  `ORS` is the Output Record Separator; this is what separates each record as it is written out.  By default is is a newline.  Here is is conditionally used as the value for the `rec` variable.

```
NF{
if (split($1, a, "_") ==3 && $1 in f1)
  p=1
  rec=(!rec)?$0:rec ORS $0
next
}
```

This last block will run only if the value of `p` is "truthy".

```
p{
  print rec ORS
  p=0; rec=""
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what does this actually mean: (split($1,a, "_") ==3) and if (split($1, a, "_") ==3 && $1 in f1)

Comment: Lots of reading [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) on those.  `split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])` will
divide `string` into pieces separated by `fieldsep` and store the pieces in `array` and the separator strings in the `seps` array.